# How to pass a date into a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to use between in a stored procedure. This is my code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_tb_sales_entry_total_product_where_date
    @to_date varchar(15),
    @from_date varchar(15)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * 
    FROM tb_sales_entry_total_product 
    WHERE [Sales Date] BETWEEN @from_date AND  @to_date
END
```

If I pass in the values `01-12-2013` and `10-01-2014` (in my table the data is also in same format) it's not returning the rows I'm expecting.

If I pass in the values `01-01-2014` and `10-01-2014` it's returning the rows I expect.

Comment: Please read this [about the sp_ prefix](https://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix), this [about date/time queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries), this [about using the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type), this [about using BETWEEN](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: And heck, this [about using semi-colons](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons), this [about using SELECT *](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list), this [about using schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), and this [best practices list](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist): SET NOCOUNT

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are passing in dates, then pass in `date`:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_tb_sales_entry_total_product_where_date
  @to_date date,
  @from_date date
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM tb_sales_entry_total_product
    WHERE [Sales Date] BETWEEN @from_date AND  @to_date
END;
```

Do the conversion to the date when the stored procedure is being called.